# How do I configure ASP.net MVC to Scaffold using ADO.net dataservice?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf-data-services

Setting up ASP.net MVC with Linq2SQL or Entity Framework's context to have scaffolding work out of the box is extremely easy. What tweaks would you make to make it work with ADO.net Data Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet there's a project for using ASP.NET Dynamic Data with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I have customized the MVC Scaffolding templates to scaffold against a WCF Data Services Context (ADO.NET Data Services, oData, which they would stop changing the name!). You can find the templates here:

http://odatascaffolding.codeplex.com/