# ASP.NET MVC 3: Automatically generating view while adding controller (without Entity Framework)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to learn MVC. I want to automatically generate the required view code as and when I add a controller. This is possible if I select the option “Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework” . However I am not using Entity Framework. How can I achieve the similar behavior without using Entity Framework? And why it is unable to  automatically generate the view when I don’t use Entity Framework?

Also, is there any good MVC3 tutorial that does not use Entity Framework (with code download available) ?

Reference

1. [How do I configure ASP.net MVC to Scaffold using ADO.net dataservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431988/how-do-i-configure-asp-net-mvc-to-scaffold-using-ado-net-dataservice)
2. Levergaing T4Scaffolding for WCF Web API
3. [ASP.NET MVC 3 and NHibernate Scaffolding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995451/asp-net-mvc-3-and-nhibernate-scaffolding)
4. Scaffold your ASP.NET MVC 3 project with the MvcScaffolding package
5. [Once again LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework for new MVC 3 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693334/once-again-linq-to-sql-or-entity-framework-for-new-mvc-3-project)
6. MVC Scaffolding for WCF Services
7. [Create a Dropdown List for MVC3 using Entity Framework (.edmx Model) & Razor Views && Insert A Database Record to Multiple Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326515/create-a-dropdown-list-for-mvc3-using-entity-framework-edmx-model-razor-vie)

Comment: Don't lose your time, create 4-5 empty controller actions and empty views manually. Automatic code generation is bonus, that allow us work faster. Is it only mean, but not goal.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer dapper if not using EF Core

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might find *some* of what you're looking for in [Steve Sanderson's MvcScaffolding package](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/mvcscaffolding-standard-usage/)

### Nuget

```
Install-Package MvcScaffolding
```

After installing (it will probably install some EF requirements) you could scaffold basic CRUD views for your model as follows assuming a model type `MySweetModel`

```
Scaffold Views MySweetModel
```

Please note this command will *not* create the controller class, but should create the following views under `/Views/MySweetModel`

- _CreateOrEdit.cshtml
- Create.cshtml
- Delete.cshtml
- Details.cshtml
- Edit.cshtml
- Index.cshtml

[It looks like you might be able to override the default T4 templates](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/06/mvcscaffolding-overriding-the-t4-templates/), but I've never used MvcScaffolding outside the scope of EF. It's also possible someone has already done this for your persistence layer e.g. NHibernate or whatever you're using. I'd search a bit before implementing your own templates.