# code generate(scaffold) in run time in asp.net mvc web application .net framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, dynamically-generated, scaffolding

I want to create scaffold item controller and the view from the model in run time I want to make an app that user can change model in run time and it automatically create controller and view based on the new model.

I have found [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Scaffolding-ASPNet-Core-MVC-1e9183fd) tutorial from which I learned how to create scaffold in command line in asp.net core MVC but I want to scaffold in asp.net web application .net framework I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328197/asp-net-mvc-3-automatically-generating-view-while-adding-controller-without-en) that has created scaffold in NuGet package but I want to scaffold automatically when user change tables in web site

Comment: What do you want to achieve by run time controller scaffolding?  Because generally it is a design  and architecture flaw.

Comment: I want to have an app that connects to crm and do crud with it. User should can change tables and fields and my app should automatically create controller and view and create forms

Comment: I never take this approach, because you can't handle run time errors properly and can't optimize database.

Comment: I haven't database my datas are in crm web service i want to connect to it and do crud with data.

Comment: My boss has told me take this approch

Comment: Which approach you think is better that meet my requirenments?

Comment: Not sure about your project details. Can you put some details of what is your use case?

Comment: I have a crm web service that have database. my app connects to this crm  and have create update and delete views and users can create update and delete  crm's datas. users also can create tables in crm, create fields or change field's type and feild's name or change table's name. and my app should automatically create forms and views for that new or changed tables and my app should have the possibility to create and update and delete with that new or changed crm's database

Comment: Based on my overall understanding of your project, It is better you create list of twin inputs in your form which one is label and other is input for that field. Then save all in database. It could be `list` of them inside your model  to have dynamic number of them. By using jq or js, user can have add button to have as many as he wants of that fields.

Comment: Thank you for your help. is this a good approach to create a model 'a' with 3 field string data type and  string display name and dynamic field's input.  when user creates  tables and fields structure based on your comment i will save these structures in a list. and then when user wants to do crud with these dynamic tables i read structures from that list  and  make an instance of model 'a' of that list's datas and crete updat and delete model a and then save to crm.

Comment: Yes, it works for your purpose. I haven't try crm but I tried it with ms sql. But remember one of the twins is only label and the other one is input. So user shouldn't able to edit lable.

Comment: tank you for your help